# How to jest mock aws-sdk function SharedIniFileCredentials

Tags: mocking, jestjs, aws-sdk

I am new to jest and trying jest mock `aws-sdk` and can't find satisfactory solution that could work on internet. I am trying to jest test when getConfig has arguments 'environment' as 'local', then `SharedIniFileCredentials` is getting called. Please refer below my test case and share your thoughts. I am getting error that `mockSharedIniFileCredentials` has never been called.

```js
// asmConfigService.ts  

import { ENVIRONMENT, AWS_DEFAULTS } from "./types";
import { SharedIniFileCredentials, SecretsManager, Credentials } from "aws-sdk";

export default class ASMConfigService {
  public static async getConfig(
    appName: string,
    environment: string,
    region: string
  ): Promise<any> {
    const config: SecretsManager.Types.ClientConfiguration = { region };

    // This helps to get properties when running the code locally

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "mylocal") {
      const credentials: Credentials = new SharedIniFileCredentials({
        profile: AWS_DEFAULTS.PROFILE
      });
      config.credentials = credentials;
    }

    const client = new SecretsManager(config);
    const secretName = `${appName}-${environment}`;

    return client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: secretName }).promise();
  }
}
```

My test case below

```js
import ASMConfigService from "./asmConfigService";
import AWS, { SAMLCredentials } from "aws-sdk";

it("should SharedIniFileCredentials be called", async () => {
  let mockSharedIniFileCredentials = jest.fn();
  jest.mock("aws-sdk", () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return { SharedIniFileCredentials: mockSharedIniFileCredentials };
    });
  });
  await ASMConfigService.getConfig(
    "personal-sat-credentials",
    "local",
    "us-east-1"
  );
  expect(mockSharedIniFileCredentials).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // gets error that this has never been called at all
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mock the `aws-sdk` module before destructuring import `SharedIniFileCredentials` and `SecretsManager` Classes in `main.ts`.

Here is the unit test solution:

`asmConfigService.ts`:

```js
import { AWS_DEFAULTS } from "./types";
import { SharedIniFileCredentials, SecretsManager, Credentials } from "aws-sdk";

export default class ASMConfigService {
  public static async getConfig(
    appName: string,
    environment: string,
    region: string
  ): Promise<any> {
    const config: SecretsManager.Types.ClientConfiguration = { region };
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "mylocal") {
      const credentials: Credentials = new SharedIniFileCredentials({
        profile: AWS_DEFAULTS.PROFILE
      });
      config.credentials = credentials;
    }
    const client = new SecretsManager(config);
    const secretName = `${appName}-${environment}`;

    return client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: secretName }).promise();
  }
}
```

`asmConfigService.test.ts`:

```js
import { AWS_DEFAULTS } from "./types";

const mSharedIniFileCredentials = jest.fn();

const mSecretsManagerInstance = {
  getSecretValue: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  promise: jest.fn()
};
const mSecretsManager = jest.fn(() => mSecretsManagerInstance);

jest.mock("aws-sdk", () => {
  return {
    SharedIniFileCredentials: mSharedIniFileCredentials,
    SecretsManager: mSecretsManager
  };
});

describe("ASMConfigService", () => {
  it("should SharedIniFileCredentials be called", async () => {
    const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;
    process.env.NODE_ENV = "mylocal";
    const ASMConfigService = require("./asmConfigService").default;
    await ASMConfigService.getConfig(
      "personal-sat-credentials",
      "local",
      "us-east-1"
    );
    expect(mSharedIniFileCredentials).toBeCalledWith({
      profile: AWS_DEFAULTS.PROFILE
    });
    expect(mSecretsManagerInstance.getSecretValue).toBeCalledWith({
      SecretId: "personal-sat-credentials-local"
    });
    expect(mSecretsManagerInstance.getSecretValue().promise).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    process.env.NODE_ENV = NODE_ENV;
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59163345/asmConfigService.test.ts
  ASMConfigService
    ✓ should SharedIniFileCredentials be called (174ms)

---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                 |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files            |      100 |       75 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 asmConfigService.ts |      100 |       50 |      100 |      100 |                11 |
 types.ts            |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.932s, estimated 9s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59163345

Comment: thanks @slideshowp2, Let me try that. Thanks. Will reply by tomorrow. I have read it twice, can't wait to implement and see. Thanks.

Comment: @reply thanks, I was able to make it work. It did work, bunch a thanks. I am new to jest and each time I read code , find something new to learn. Thanks again.